# People you may know using MapReduce in python

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I've trying to build people you may know using MapReduce in python such that it should display result for people(top 5) with maximum no. recommendation.
The data set is in the format of

```
<user_id><tab space><friend_1_id,friend_2_id_2, . . .>
```

the code I've used is.
Explanation: http://andresromero.github.io/People-you-may-know/

**Mapper**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import itertools
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split("\t")
    key = int(line[0])
    if len(line)>1:
        friends = line[1]
        if friends!='':
            friends = line[1].split(",")
            friends = sorted(map(int,friends))
            for friend in friends:
                pair = tuple(sorted([key,friend]))
                pair = ','.join(map(str,pair))
                print pair,"\t",1
            for pair in itertools.combinations(friends,2):
                pair = ','.join(map(str,pair))
                print pair,"\t",0
```

**Reducer**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import itertools
import sys

flist={}
def checking(k,size):
    if len(flist)==0 | len(flist)<5:
        return 0
    elif len(flist) > 5:
        for i in flist.keys():
            if len(flist[i]) < size:
                return i;
    else:
        return -1
def addPair(users,k1,k2,friendFlag):
    if friendFlag==1:
        friendFlag = True
    else:
        friendFlag = False

    if k1 not in users:
        users[k1] = {}
        users[k1][k2] = [1,False]
    else:
        if k2 in users[k1]:
            users[k1][k2][0] += 1            
        else:
            users[k1][k2] = [1,False]
    if friendFlag==True:
        users[k1][k2][0] -= 1
        users[k1][k2][1] = True

users = {}

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    line = line.split("\t")
    key = tuple(map(int,line[0].strip().split(",")))
    friendFlag = int(line[1])
    k1,k2 = key
    addPair(users,k1,k2,friendFlag)
    addPair(users,k2,k1,friendFlag)
for k1 in users.keys():
    recommendations = []
    for k2 in users[k1].keys():
        n,flag = users[k1][k2]
        if flag==False:
            recommendations.append((k2,n))
    recommendations = sorted(recommendations,key=lambda x: x[0])
    recommendations = sorted(recommendations,key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)
    if len(recommendations)>0:
        recommendations = list(map(str,zip(*recommendations)[0]))
        flag=checking(k1,len(recommendations))
        if flag==0:
            flist[k1]=[]
            flist[k1]=recommendations
            temp3 = sorted(flist.items(), key = lambda item : len(item[1]))
            flist = dict(temp3)
        elif flag!= -1:
            flist[k1]=flist.pop(flag)
            flist.update({k1,recommendations})
            temp3 = sorted(flist.items(), key = lambda item : len(item[1]))
            flist = dict(temp3)
        #print k1,"\t",','.join(recommendations[:-1])
for i in flist.keys():
    print i,"has", len(flist[i])," recommendations"
```

But the result I'm getting is as

```
0 has 830  recommendations  
1 has 1802  recommendations 
2 has 499  recommendations  
3 has 309  recommendations  
4 has 245  recommendations
```

but the person with maximum recommendation is 8685 with 4600 recommendations

Comment: "Works perfectly fine" -> this question would better suit CodeReview SE.

Comment: Please Elaborate what are you suggesting.